# Every time I run Excel 2010, Windows Installer tries to configure it

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, windows-installer

Recently, after a pushed update from Microsoft (using Windows 10 and Office 2010), I began having a problem. Every time I ran Excel I would get this message:

[image]

A few moments later, it changed to this:

[image]

and then:

[image]

Of course, I couldn't tell it where to find the **Microsoft Office Single Image 2010** file it sought (I looked everywhere using [SwiftSearch](https://sourceforge.net/projects/swiftsearch/)), so I would cancel, get another error message and then it would start all over again... (argh)

I quickly learned to hit Cancel as soon as the first message appeared and a few moments later I could use Excel. But it was an ongoing annoyance that wouldn't go away. Searching the web turned up lots of things that did not work, including running EXCEL.EXE directly. Finally, today, I figured out the source of the problem and resolved it. See my answer below...

Comment: meiryo.ttc = Japanese Sans-Serriff Gothic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiryo). I wonder if you might have used, inserted, copy/paste, any Japanese characters. Maybe added Japanese to your languages in Options in Word? Another fix might have been to find a safe download of this Font from a trusted site.

Comment: Didn't do any Japanese. Didn't need to find the font on the web, since it had already been left behind on my computer, probably when I installed Office 2010, which includes it. In any case, if you check the MS page I referenced in the answer, you'll see it's a commercial font & would need to be licensed from Monotype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in the Event Viewer log, I found that every time Excel started there was a series of entries and the first one was always this:

> Detection of product '{90140000-003D-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}', feature
>   'ProductNonBootFiles',  component
>   '{B3D474BE-E3A6-49C8-B1DA-68D117BD8DC7}' failed.   The resource
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\MEIRYO.TTC' does not exist.

A web search turned up [this page showing MEIRYO is a Microsoft font for CJK languages](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1595) (which I don't actually use or need...). That page notes it is supplied with Office 2010 (among others).

I used SwiftSearch and discovered that the font file in question was present on my computer in this location:

> C:\Windows\Installer\$PatchCache$\Managed\00004119B30000000100000000F01FEC\14.0.4763

I went there and found it and also MEIRYOB.TTC. Did right-click and 'Install' on both of them.

Restarted Excel & the problem is gone!

My estimation is that Microsoft either created a dependency on that font for Excel (without ensuring it is installed) or somehow uninstalled it during one of the upgrades.

My advice: If you encounter this problem, start at the event log.

1. Right click on "Computer" on your desktop / start menu and hit "Manage".
2. Under "System Tools", expand "Event Viewer", "Windows Logs", and select "Application".
3. On the right, click "Filter Current Log"
4. In the new dialog, for the "Event sources" drop down list, select "MsiInstaller" & click "OK"

That will filter the log to all Windows installer related actions. Click "Find..." on the right to search for "Product: Microsoft Office Single Image 2010 -- Configuration failed."

Go back to the beginning of that sequence of MsiInstaller messages and see what triggered it. It may be the same as my case or perhaps you'll find something different.  Good luck.

Comment: A pushed upgrade. Sound like sneakiness is going on. Thank goodness you are keen to technology or you might have gone out and bought the newest upgrade; had you called support they might have suggested it? Good work.

Comment: What OS are you using? I looked at that font code and found that a gamer had a similar issue. Weird. http://closershq.com/Discussion-Failed-Font-Loading-meiryo-ttc

Comment: meiryo.ttc = Japanese Sans-Serriff Gothic. I wonder if you might have used, inserted, copy/paste, any Japanese characters or maybe added Japanese to your languages in Options in Word?

Comment: @ejbytes - nope - I haven't done anything with Japanese. But even if I had, the search for it should have happened at the time I attempted to use it. In any case, there is already a unicode font for all possible characters. As I wrote, I think someone at MS inadvertently created a dependency on the font for one of the updates that was pushed out for Excel. Re: OS - as I wrote, Windows 10.